# calculate correlation between one column and a selection of other columns without loop

Tags: r

```
w= as.numeric()
for(i in 2:10)){
    w[i] = cor(a[,1], a[,i], method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
 }
```

Is there anyway to convert the following for loop to one line of code, like below?

```
w[1:9] = cor(a[,1], a[,i], method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs")
```

Comment: @underscore_d Thanks! Just did :)

Comment: `sapply(c(2:10), function(x) cor(a[,1], a[,x], method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs") )`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
w = sapply(c(2:10), function(x) cor(a[,1], a[,x], method = "pearson", use = 'pairwise.complete.obs') )
```

Assuming the reason you're using `2:10` is because there are 10 cols. If that's the case and you want it to be more dynamic:

```
w = sapply(c(2:ncol(a)), function(x) cor(a[,1], a[,x], method = "pearson", use = "complete.obs") )
```

Finally, if you don't want to use the apply family, you can generate the entire `cor` matrix and extract what you need from the first row:

```
w = cor(a, method = 'pearson', use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')[1,-1]
```

Reproducible example:

```
> a = iris[,1:4]
> cor(a, method = 'pearson', use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')[1,-1]
 Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
 -0.1175698    0.8717538    0.8179411
```

**Edit:**
If you want to retrieve the correlation for a different column (say 2):

```
> cor(a, method = 'pearson', use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')[2,-2]
Sepal.Length Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
-0.1175698   -0.4284401   -0.3661259
```

Also, per Joris Meys' suggestion, make sure to use `'pairwise.complete.obs'`

Comment: Thanks @Tgsmith61591, `sapply` works, but if I don't want to use it and instead of the 1st value, i want to correlate with another value in the middle of a, how would `[1,2:ncol(a)]` change? Like can I use `[5, 1:4 & 6:10]`?

Comment: @Christa, I updated my answer to be more robust to your situation. If this solves your problem, please mark this answer as the solution!

Comment: Both solutions give different results. If you use 'complete.obs' in sapply(), it is the equivalent of using 'pairwise.complete.obx' when using cor() to create the whole matrix.

Comment: Thank you, it threw an error first, saying there are no element pairs, but worked with use = 'pairwise.complete.obs' as @JorisMeys mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @Christa I updated to include the 'pairwise.complete.obs'

Comment: on a sidenote: your solution still calculates a whole series of correlation coefficients that are not needed. The best solution would still be to use cor() as it is anticipated (see also my solution). That way you only calculate what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily by specifying a matrix as the y argument of cor():

```
> a <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)
> colnames(a) <- LETTERS[1:5]
> cor(a[,2], a[,c(3:5,1)], use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
             C         D          E           A
[1,] 0.3096647 0.6383469 -0.3527352 -0.08329776
```

This avoids the calculation of correlations you're not interested in. If you would select the relevant correlations from `cor(a)`, you would also be calculating all the correlations between the other columns.

Note that -unlike you do in the `sapply()` solution- you need to set `use` to `pairwise.complete.obs`.  Otherwise R will drop all rows where there's a missing value in one of the columns.

See also `?cor`